# Record not found in table "tableA" with primary key ['2']

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I try to edit, delete or view the records.

```
/cakefacility/tableAs/view/2
```

I get an error message:

```
Record not found in table "tableA" with primary key ['2']
```

I have this registry in DB

**`tableA`**

```
id  tableB_id      name
1   1              qwe
2   1              asd
```

**`Controller`**

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $tableA= $this->TableA->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['TableB']
    ]);
    $this->set('tableA', $tableA);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['tableA']);
}
```

The error is in the get() method.

[TableA model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9xtW.jpg)

[TableA data (condominio_id = tableB_id)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ8E7.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code for your controller.

Comment: @InigoFlores, I edited my Post and add the code, I don´t know if it´s the correct step.

Comment: I take out the primary keys of the table in the DB structure and baked all the table, then I put the PK and baked again and now it is working. I don´t know why, but it´s working.

Comment: Yes, make sure your table has a primary key defined, not a index key. That fixed this error for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```php
$tableA= $this->TableA->get($id)->contain('TableB')
```